# How to name dictionary/list with variable

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, dictionary

I get fed JSON data and I need to create a varying amount of dictionaries to store events in. I can't seem to figure out or find and answer to something like this:

Creating a Dictionary:

```
foreach (Identity x in List.Identities)
{
    Dictionary<int, int> shop + x.Id = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    Dictionary<int, int> de + x.Id = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    Dictionary<int, int> sell + x.Id = new Dictionary<int, int>();
}
```

So that later I can also input the varying number of events with max efficiency:

```
foreach (Event x in y.events)
{
    if ((x.Type.Contains("PURCHASED")){        
        shop+x.Id.Add(x.timestamp, x.item);
    }
    if ((x.Type.Contains("SOLD")){
        sell+x.Id.Add(x.timestamp, x.item);
    }
    if ((x.Type.Contains("DESTROYED")){
        de+x.Id.Add(x.timestamp, x.item);
    }
}
```

I know this is definitely NOT the way to declare these, but I can't find a way to have an `int` variable declared in the dictionary name. If this works with lists, that would work as well, anything that I can `foreach`. Thanks!

Here's the classes to avoid confusion:

```
public class Event
        {
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public int timestamp { get; set; }
            public int item { get; set; }
            public int Id { get; set; }
        }

public class ParticipantIdentity
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: You could store them by name in another dictionary: `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>>`

Comment: Do you really have multiple events with the same ID? Your model is pretty confusing to me at the moment.

Comment: Any given event can have up to 7 different types and up to 12 different ID's. In the whole list of events, probably about 15+ will be for each ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. Variable names in C# are never dynamic - it sounds like you want a map from ID to "dictionary of timestamp to item".

In fact, I would probably create a separate type of `ItemEvents` or something similar, which contained all the events for items with a single ID - e.g. by having three dictionaries within it.

You'd then just need:

```
var eventsByItem = List.Identities.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                       .Select(g => new ItemEvents(g.Key, g))
                       .
```

where the `ItemEvents` constructor would do the splitting, e.g.

```
public ItemEvents(int id, IEnumerable<Event> events)
{
    this.id = id;
    shops = events.Where(e => e.Type.Contains("PURCHASED"))
                  .ToDictionary(e => e.timestamp, e => e.item);
    // Ditto for the other dictionaries.
}
```

As an aside, I would try to use a more meaningful type than `int` for a timestamp - and consider using an `enum` for the event type.

Answer (score 2):

You can create yet another set of dictionaries, with `x.Id` being a key:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> shops = Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>;
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> des = Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>;
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> sells = Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>;
```

So later you can do this:

```
foreach (Identity x in List.Identities)
{
    shops[x.Id] = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    ...
}
```

and this:

```
if ((x.Type.Contains("PURCHASED")){        
    shops[x.Id].Add(x.timestamp, x.item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a dirctionary of dictionaries:

```
var shops = new Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int, int>>();

foreach (Identity x in List.Identities)
{
     shops.Add(x.Id,new Dictionary<int, int>());
    //des and shells the same way
}
```

and then

```
foreach (Event x in y.events)
{
    if ((x.Type.Contains("PURCHASED")){        
        shops[x.Id].Add(x.timestamp, x.item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know, you can't dynamically create variable names like that.

You *could* create a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
var dictionaries = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>>();
foreach (Identity x in List.Identities)
{
    dictionaries.add("shop" + x.Id, new Dictionary<int, int>());
    dictionaries.add("de" + x.Id, new Dictionary<int, int>());
    dictionaries.add("sell" + x.Id, new Dictionary<int, int>());
}
```

```
foreach (Event x in y.events)
{
    if ((x.Type.Contains("PURCHASED")){        
        dictionaries["shop"+x.Id].Add(x.timestamp, x.item);
    }
    if ((x.Type.Contains("SOLD")){
        dictionaries["sell"+x.Id].Add(x.timestamp, x.item);
    }
    if ((x.Type.Contains("DESTROYED")){
        dictionaries["de"+x.Id].Add(x.timestamp, x.item);
    }
}
```